# Base64 encoding and decoding in oracle

Tags: oracle, base64

How can I do Base64 encode/decode a value in Oracle?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I've implemented this to send Cyrillic e-mails through my MS Exchange server.

```
function to_base64(t in varchar2) return varchar2 is
 begin
    return utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(t)));
end to_base64;
```

Try it.

**upd:** after a minor adjustment I came up with this, so it works both ways now:

```
function from_base64(t in varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
  return utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(t)));
end from_base64;
```

You can check it:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> 
SQL> declare
  2    function to_base64(t in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  3    begin
  4      return utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(t)));
  5    end to_base64;
  6  
  7    function from_base64(t in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  8    begin
  9      return utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw    (t)));
 10    end from_base64;
 11  
 12  begin
 13    dbms_output.put_line(from_base64(to_base64('asdf')));
 14  end;
 15  /

asdf

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

**upd2:** Ok, here's a sample conversion that works for `CLOB` I just came up with. Try to work it out for your blobs. :)

```
declare

  clobOriginal     clob;
  clobInBase64     clob;
  substring        varchar2(2000);
  n                pls_integer := 0;
  substring_length pls_integer := 2000;

  function to_base64(t in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  begin
    return utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(t)));
  end to_base64;

  function from_base64(t in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  begin
    return utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(t)));
  end from_base64;

begin

  select clobField into clobOriginal from clobTable where id = 1;

  while true loop

    /*we substract pieces of substring_length*/
    substring := dbms_lob.substr(clobOriginal,
                                 least(substring_length, substring_length * n + 1 - length(clobOriginal)),
                                 substring_length * n + 1);  
    /*if no substring is found  - then we've reached the end of blob*/

    if substring is null then
      exit;
    end if;  

    /*convert them to base64 encoding and stack it in new clob vadriable*/
    clobInBase64 := clobInBase64 || to_base64(substring);          
    n := n + 1;  

  end loop;

  n := 0;
  clobOriginal := null;

  /*then we do the very same thing backwards - decode base64*/
  while true loop 

    substring := dbms_lob.substr(clobInBase64,
                                 least(substring_length, substring_length * n + 1 - length(clobInBase64)),
                                 substring_length * n + 1);  
    if substring is null then
      exit;
    end if;  
    clobOriginal := clobOriginal || from_base64(substring);  
    n := n + 1;  
  end loop; 

      /*and insert the data in our sample table - to ensure it's the same*/
  insert into clobTable (id, anotherClobField) values (1, clobOriginal);

end;
```

Comment: works pretty well for me though I get spaces in the middle of my encoding. I put a regular expression space replace around my result and I'm in business: regexp_replace(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(t))), '[[:space:]]*','')

Comment: There is a small bug in your second update: The "amount" parameter of the dbms_log.substr should be  "least(substring_length,  length(clobInBase64) - (substring_length * n + 1) )". The way you wrote it returns a negative amount, so the substring is always empty.

Comment: BASE64 encoding takes 3 Bytes of input stream and converts it to 4 * 3 Bytes. Each of these 3 Bytes are mapped to 64 different characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, "+", "/" - thus you get name BASE64). Ensure that value of substring_length is a whole multiple of 4 for `BASE64_DECODE`, resp. a whole multiple of 3 for `BASE64_ENCODE`. Thus your `to_base64` function may return wrong result.

Comment: I get '\r\n' every after every 64character, how do I remove them??

Answer (score 15):

Solution with `utl_encode.base64_encode` and `utl_encode.base64_decode` have one limitation, they work only with strings up to 32,767 characters/bytes.

In case you have to convert bigger strings you will face several obstacles.

- For `BASE64_ENCODE` the function has to read 3 **Bytes** and transform them. In case of Multi-Byte characters (e.g. `öäüè€` stored at UTF-8, aka `AL32UTF8`) 3 **Character** are not necessarily also 3 **Bytes**. In order to read always 3 Bytes you have to convert your `CLOB` into `BLOB` first.
- The same problem applies for `BASE64_DECODE`. The function has to read 4 Bytes and transform them into 3 Bytes. Those 3 **Bytes** are not necessarily also 3 **Characters**
- Typically a BASE64-String has NEW_LINE (`CR` and/or `LF`) character each 64 characters. Such new-line characters have to be ignored while decoding.

Taking all this into consideration the full featured solution could be this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DecodeBASE64(InBase64Char IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) RETURN CLOB IS

    blob_loc BLOB;
    clob_trim CLOB;
    res CLOB;

    lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
    dest_offset INTEGER := 1;
    src_offset INTEGER := 1;
    read_offset INTEGER := 1;
    warning INTEGER;
    ClobLen INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(InBase64Char);

    amount INTEGER := 1440; -- must be a whole multiple of 4
    buffer RAW(1440);
    stringBuffer VARCHAR2(1440);
    -- BASE64 characters are always simple ASCII. Thus you get never any Mulit-Byte character and having the same size as 'amount' is sufficient

BEGIN

    IF InBase64Char IS NULL OR NVL(ClobLen, 0) = 0 THEN 
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSIF ClobLen<= 32000 THEN
        RETURN UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(InBase64Char)));
    END IF;        
    -- UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE is limited to 32k, process in chunks if bigger    

    -- Remove all NEW_LINE from base64 string
    ClobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(InBase64Char);
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(clob_trim, TRUE);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN read_offset > ClobLen;
        stringBuffer := REPLACE(REPLACE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(InBase64Char, amount, read_offset), CHR(13), NULL), CHR(10), NULL);
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(clob_trim, LENGTH(stringBuffer), stringBuffer);
        read_offset := read_offset + amount;
    END LOOP;

    read_offset := 1;
    ClobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(clob_trim);
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(blob_loc, TRUE);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN read_offset > ClobLen;
        buffer := UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(clob_trim, amount, read_offset)));
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(blob_loc, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(buffer), buffer);
        read_offset := read_offset + amount;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(res, TRUE);
    DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOCLOB(res, blob_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, dest_offset, src_offset,  DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_context, warning);

    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(blob_loc);
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(clob_trim);
    RETURN res;    

END DecodeBASE64;




CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EncodeBASE64(InClearChar IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) RETURN CLOB IS

    dest_lob BLOB;  
    lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
    dest_offset INTEGER := 1;
    src_offset INTEGER := 1;
    read_offset INTEGER := 1;
    warning INTEGER;
    ClobLen INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(InClearChar);

    amount INTEGER := 1440; -- must be a whole multiple of 3
    -- size of a whole multiple of 48 is beneficial to get NEW_LINE after each 64 characters 
    buffer RAW(1440);
    res CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();

BEGIN

    IF InClearChar IS NULL OR NVL(ClobLen, 0) = 0 THEN 
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSIF ClobLen <= 24000 THEN
        RETURN UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(InClearChar)));
    END IF;
    -- UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE is limited to 32k/(3/4), process in chunks if bigger    

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(dest_lob, TRUE);
    DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB(dest_lob, InClearChar, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, dest_offset, src_offset, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_context, warning);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN read_offset >= dest_offset;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(dest_lob, amount, read_offset, buffer);
        res := res || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(buffer));       
        read_offset := read_offset + amount;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(dest_lob);
    RETURN res;

END EncodeBASE64;
```

Comment: At 19c, does utl_encode.base64_encode and utl_encode.base64_decode support only 4000 chars if max string size flag is set to standard and not extended? Or is the standard for these functions now 32767 chars now?

Comment: According to my knowledge `utl_encode.base64_encode` and `utl_encode.base64_decode` always supports up to 32767. The limit is not given by `VARCHAR2` [column data type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020), it is given by [PL/SQL data type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS332) `VARCHAR2`

Answer (score 3):

All the previous posts are correct. There's more than one way to skin a cat. Here is another way to do the same thing: (just replace "what_ever_you_want_to_convert" with your string and run it in Oracle:

```
    set serveroutput on;
    DECLARE
    v_str VARCHAR2(1000);
    BEGIN
    --Create encoded value
    v_str := utl_encode.text_encode
    ('what_ever_you_want_to_convert','WE8ISO8859P1', UTL_ENCODE.BASE64);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
    --Decode the value..
    v_str := utl_encode.text_decode
    (v_str,'WE8ISO8859P1', UTL_ENCODE.BASE64);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
    END;
    /
```

[source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_utl_encode.htm)

Answer (score -5):

do `url_raw.cast_to_raw()` support in oracle 6