# Inserting binary data into Varchar2 with OTL (OCCI, OCI)

Tags: oracle-call-interface, varchar2, occi, otl

How do I insert data that might be binary into a Varchar2 with OTL?
(OCI/OCCI would be OK of course)

Background: We have a lot of Varchar2 columns  which are generally not binary, but it might happen somewhere someday (I am especially concerned about \0 and UTF-8)

Tuesday:  I posted this related question:
[How can I store bytes in Oracle Varchar2, and have ASCII treated as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452931/how-can-i-store-bytes-in-oracle-varchar2-and-have-ascii-treated-as-text)

Comment: Why do you wish to use the VARCHAR2 data type?

Answer (score 1):

If you must use VARCHAR2, you'll need to convert the binary data first, for example using BASE-64 encoding.

So if you're calling an insert statement from C++, you first in C [encode the bytes you wish to insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c), then call the statement to insert the resulting string.

If you wish to insert binary values from another table, it gets trickier, but you can [encode them in a PL/SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle).

But if you can alter the data type, it is probably better to use the RAW datatype instead.

Comment: How would this look with BASE-64: +  res "INSERT INTO HEADER_TBNAME VALUES(:BF_FILE_CREATION_DATE<char[5]>?

Comment: Here's someone who does it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle

Comment: Yes, but that is in a stored procedure?  Or at least PL/SQL in the C++?

Comment: If the binary object you wish to insert sits on the C++ side, you can encode it using a C library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342409/how-do-i-base64-encode-decode-in-c

Comment: Am I right that this involves having the data encoded as BASE-64 IN THE DATABASE?  That is not what I am looking for (Unless it is not technically possible to have some binary data in a varchar2)

Comment: No, binary data cannot be written into a VARCHAR2 column.