# How can I store bytes in Oracle Varchar2, and have ASCII treated as text

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, varchar2

How can I have bytes stored in a Varchar2, and have it treated "normally" as text when it is ASCII for example?  (Like in queries).

If not possible, where is the limitation?

I know the column is defined with a character sets, so if it is ANSI for example, what kind of 1-byte values can I not put there?  Are there "better" solutions than ANSI for 1-byte character sets?

Answer (score -1):

You have to encode bytes into text. You can use `rawtohex` function or `utl_encode` package. For displaying characters you have to use inverse function and then convert raw bytes to varchar2. Use `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2`.

Comment: Then I can't treat it as text

Comment: Could you provide some example?