# How to extract compressed BLOB to string using PL / SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, blob

```
create table testblob
(
  id number,
  desc blob
);
```

Column DESC is loaded by web application ( Zipped XML is loaded into testblob.desc)

Aim : PL SQL to extract the content and send a readable xml to process using XML Parser in Informatica.

Suggest some method to extract compressed/zipped BLOB into string ( which contains the XML content) supporting huge values.

DB : 11g.

Comment: What do you mean? Like, base64 encoding or similar? You could try [raw](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3804279/266304), but what does Informatica expect or understand?

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted and closed as off-topic.  This sounds like a regular programming question to me, and may even have a relatively easy answer: [UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_compr.htm#ARPLS381).

Comment: Valid, though perhaps sketchy on detail question. I speak as a victim of this myself. Anyway, in  PLSQL there is no real "string" type. A BLOB is a BLOB. So, write a procedure to RETURN the BLOB, and use the appropriate interface in Informatica to read the BLOB. Or, as suggested us UTL_COMPRESS within the stored procedure to uncompress the zipped BLOB data, and write it to a XMLTYpe, and return the XMLTYpe.getClob .. that should go into a Java String/CLOB equivalent (assuming Informatica understands Java).