# how to store an excel file from FTP server into oracle using PLSQ developer

Tags: excel, plsql, ftp, plsqldeveloper

i get few excel files via FTP server i want to save those files into my table in clob using plsql developer.

Comment: `CLOB` can't store binary data. If it is a simple csv file , you could use CLOB. Use `BLOB` or `BFILE` instead depending on your storage affordability

Comment: Since word, excel files are rar/zip files you could convert it to `base64` and then store it into a `CLOB`. [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle)