# encoding and decoding in oracle select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, encoding

Is there a way i can encode a string from a select statement in oracle.

i.e.

```
SELECT base64encode('mystring') FROM dual; --this doesn't work
```

base64 or any other encoding mechanism is welcomed. one that can be decoded

Comment: "Hash" has the distinct characteristic that it **cannot** be "decoded". Encoding/decoding is quite different from hashing; both are very important and each has numerous important applications, but their areas of application do not overlap. I will edit your post to remove any reference to "hashing", as obviously you want to encode and decode, not to hash.

Comment: Alright @mathguy .Understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle has the `UTL_ENCODE` package, including the `BASE64_ENCODE` and `BASE64_DECODE` functions. Both functions work on `RAW` data type (both the input and the return value are `RAW`); so, if you want to use this for character data types, like `VARCHAR2` or perhaps `CLOB`, you need to use additional conversions - as found in the `UTL_RAW` package; functions like `CAST_TO_RAW` and `CAST_TO_VARCHAR2`.

Here is a brief example. I start with the string `'mathguy'` (in `VARCHAR2` data type); first I convert it to `RAW`, and then I encode it `to base64`. Then, to demonstrate the decoding step, I apply the `BASE64_DECODE` function to the output from the first query, and convert the resulting `RAW` value back to `VARCHAR2`; the result of the second query should be the input of the first. Let's see:

```
select utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('mathguy')) as encoded
from   dual;

/* ENCODING */

ENCODED
------------------------
625746306147643165513D3D


/* DECODING */

select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
         utl_encode.base64_decode('625746306147643165513D3D')) as decoded
from   dual;

DECODED
-----------
mathguy
```

**Edit** Please see Wernfried Domscheit's Comment below: the `RAW` data type is limited to 2000 bytes, or 32767 bytes with extended max string size. So this may not work as shown here for very long input strings.

Comment: Functions `utl_encode.base64_encode()/utl_encode.base64_decode()` work only up to 32k characters. In case you need more see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle/3806265#40852152

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - Good point, but the limit is not imposed by the functions. Rather, the `RAW` datatype itself is limited to 2000 bytes, or 32k bytes with extended max string size. Note that the limit is 32k bytes; this may be less than 32k characters, in multi-byte character sets. It is also possible that the encoding of a < 2000 B (or < 32 kB) `RAW` results in a `RAW` longer than the limit...

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit lucky for now i wanted a simple one since i will be encoding only 10-15 characters. It is helpful you have pointed that out aswell