# convert raw text to_char in oracle dbeaver

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i return below encoded result to char

```
SELECT  utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('some_text')) COLM FROM DUAL;
```

I have tried

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('some_text'))) COLM FROM DUAL;

-- I get error: SQL Error [932] [42000]: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
```

Reason why i need it in char/text is because i find it difficult  to copy the result from dbeaver since dbeaver recognizes the result as an encrypted data hence encrypts it further or exports empty result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle

Comment: BASE64 encoded **does not** mean "encrypted"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2` on the `RAW` value you've got:

```sql
SELECT  utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
          utl_encode.base64_encode(
            utl_raw.cast_to_raw('some_text')
          )
        ) COLM
FROM    DUAL;
```

outputs:

> ```
> | COLM         |
> | :----------- |
> | c29tZV90ZXh0 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=48db816fa61aeb5178c484f1f5cf1ae5)*

Comment: Thanks great answer, can you explain why in general `TO_CHAR('some_text')` brings the error `inconsistent datatypes`: ?

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa `TO_CHAR( 'some text!' )` doesn't give any errors [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a946cd7f50960bb75105929227ae753c). But if you are asking why it give errors after you convert it to a `RAW` data type; that's because `TO_CHAR` can't handle `RAW`s and you need to use a function designed to handle that data type such as `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2` to do the conversion.