# How to store Japanese character in ORACLE DB without changing type of column VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, insert

I want to insert Japanese characters into a VARCHAR2 column type without changing this type to NVARCHAR.
Is it possible ?
Here are the characteristics of my DB (and without changing these characteristics too)

[image]

Thank you for help.

Comment: You would need to change the encoding of the entire database instance (if that's even possible), so I'd say you cannot. Your only other option is to serialise as ASCII (e.g. Base64).

Comment: As @ÁlvaroGonzález said, this is not possible. In order to change text to BASE64 string see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804279/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-oracle/3806265#40852152

Comment: Can you give me an example to serialize in ASCII ?